# I cannot fix this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Tags: javascript, module, jestjs

I am exporting my js file, so I can use import into my unit test file. Here is my js file:

```
function getComputerChoice() {
  //stuff here
}
        
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  //stuff here 
}
    
function game() {
  // stuff
} 
    
module.exports = {
  getComputerChoice,
  playRound,
  game,
};
```

And in my test file, I am importing it this way:

```
const rockPaperScissors = require('../rockPaperScissors');

test('Verify the case for tie', () => {
  expect(rockPaperScissors.playRound('rock', 'rock')).toBe('TIE');
});
test('Verify the case for win', () => {
  expect(rockPaperScissors.playRound('rock', 'scissors')).toBe('WIN');
});
test('Verify the case for lose', () => {
  expect(rockPaperScissors.playRound('rock', 'paper')).toBe('LOSE');
});
```

The only way I can get my test file to work, is by exporting in the above format, but when I run the index.html in for this page, I see `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`.

Comment: seems like you're trying to run the code in a browser, and the error you're getting is saying that the module is not defined. If this code is intended to be run in a browser, you'll have to package it with Webpack or Browserify first

Comment: Yes, I'm just running this in my browser console. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, you need to compile it to plain javascript to run this in browser console. browser won't understand the module object.

Answer (score 3):

`require` and `module.exports` are part of the [CommonJS module system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) which is Node.js' default module system.

Browsers have no support for CommonJS so if you want to use code written using it you will need to convert it to a format that browsers do support. Typically this is done using a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

Browsers do support [standard JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (so long as you load them with `<script type="module">`) which use `import` and `export` so you could also rewrite your modules to use that.